# Automatically show related contacts of accounts in dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, contacts, microsoft-dynamics, accounts

One of my client want to allow their users to view the related contacts of an account, even if they are not shared with them. I've suggested some solutions that were including workflows, plugins or teams. But he is still insisting that if a user can access to accounts then he should have access to the related contacts.

Can anybody is there to share his views on it.

Comment: CRM 2013 and later provide an out of the box solution, is upgrading a viable option for you ?

Comment: can you please add more about the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If upgrading is an option for you, 2013 and later have Access Teams which are meant for sharing permissions without messing the ownership.

Lots of useful info here http://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/11/24/crm-2013-new-features-access-teams/

Basically, once you enable Access Teams for an entity, you can relate Users to a specific record and those users will gain access to the record itself (in a manner similar to Sharing, but you can define templates) *and child records too* if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing through teams or directly to a user is the only answer you can give to your customer.